# NextJs Error-> Server Error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: next.js, react-hooks

I really dont know where this error is coming from, I already check all components import and usage. I even thought it was because of something about the Layout component, but there isn't nothing to do with him or anything.

Acess the issue in the repository for more details: https://github.com/DevDario/quicktranslator/issues/7

`logs`:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
useContext
file:///C:/Users/Da/Desktop/quicktranslator/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (1618:21)
_routercontext
..\node_modules\next\dist\client\image-component.js (241:47)
renderWithHooks
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderForwardRef
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5842:18)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6005:11)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderHostElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5642:3)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5952:5)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderHostElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5642:3)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5952:5)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5971:9)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5785:7)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5785:7)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5785:7)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderChildrenArray
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6211:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6141:7)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5971:9)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/Da/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
```

I've tried to delete the `Layout` import from certains external components,and also checked all components prop values, but nothing helped